# Testing for iOS 4.3 on Xcode 4.3 and iOS 5.1 development environment

Tags: ios, ios5.1

I have been trying to test my app developed for iOS 5.1 on iOS 4.3 simulator but somehow it is complaining that the framework files are missing for iOS 4.3. I have installed the iPhone 4.3 simulator through the organizer but to no avail. I have also tried other options of setting UIKit framework as optional but that did not work.

Do I need to reinstall previous version of SDK to test this or is there some simple solution?

Comment: would like to know that two.... how should I resolve old bugs..

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode, open the Simulator menu. There's a menu item named "More Simulators"

[image: More Simulator]

Choosing that menu item opens another window where you'll be able to choose to download and install additional Xcode content.

[image: Option to install]